# How to send send commands to Iot devices from google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, iot, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to use google cloudiot api from a google cloud function written in python. When I make http requests to the Cloud IoT api, I get a 403 "forbidden' error. I have authenticated using a service account with full permissions.

import os
from flask import json
import base64

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db

import googleapiclient
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(options={'databaseURL': 'https://lucid-v2-1.firebaseio.com/'})

def get_client(service_account_json):
    """Returns an authorized API client by discovering the IoT API and creating
    a service object using the service account credentials JSON."""
    api_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudiot']
    api_version = 'v1'
    discovery_api = 'https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'
    service_name = 'cloudiotcore'

```
#credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_json)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_json)
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(api_scopes)

discovery_url = '{}?version={}'.format(
        discovery_api, api_version)

print(credentials.service_account_email)

return discovery.build(
        service_name,
        api_version,
        discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url,
        credentials=scoped_credentials,
        cache_discovery=False)
```

def request_posted(event, context):

```
print(os.environ)
#
client = get_client(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'))
"""Triggered by a change to a Firebase RTDB reference.
Args:
     event (dict): Event payload.
     context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.

"""

print(client)

resources = context.resource.split('/')
request_id = resources[-1]
request_values = event['delta']

response_ref = db.reference("experience_channel/responses/" + str(request_id))
response_ref.update({"ack":True})

db.reference("experience_channel/experience_data")

device_id = "2593786060198708"
project_id = "lucid-iOS-v2-1"
cloud_region = "us-central1"
registry_id = "Lucid_IoT_Registry"
device_path = 'projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}/devices/{}'.format(project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id)

print(device_path)
epoch_length = 20

message_contents = {
"experience_id":request_id,
"epoch_length":epoch_length,
"experience_length":request_values['length']
}

message_json = json.dumps(message_contents)

test_body = "test_body"

command_body = {
    'binaryData': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
        message_json.encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii'),
    'subfolder' : 'commands'
}

#client.projects().locations().registries().testIamPermissions(resource = )


print(client.projects(
    ).locations().registries(
    ).devices().list(parent = "projects/lucid-iOS-v2-1/locations/us-central1/registries/Lucid_IoT_Registry").execute())

resp = client.projects(
    ).locations().registries(
    ).devices().sendCommandToDevice(
    name = device_path, body = command_body).execute()

print(resp)

return resp
```

Comment: When you say "service account with full permission", can you tell me which roles specifically that service account has? That might be an issue. Also, were you able to access the Cloud IoT Core API locally (not through Cloud Functions)? It might be important to isolate the issue to whether it is Cloud Functions specific, or if the 403 happens elsewhere as well.

Comment: Where is `service_account_json` defined? Have you dumped the variable to confirm it's there and that you're using the service account you think you are? Depending on how that's handled, you might be getting a default service account which doesn't have the right permissions.

Comment: You may be incorrectly specifying `'subfolder': 'commands'`. The API documentation suggests that by specifying a subfolder, you'll get to `/devices/{device-id}/commands/{subfolder}`, so you may be incorrectly attempting to use `.../commands/commands`. See https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudiot/v1/python/latest/cloudiot_v1.projects.locations.registries.devices.html#sendCommandToDevice

Comment: Not (!) that this will solve your issue but -- unless you've a need to stick with the older API Client Library -- there's a more modern (idiomatic) Cloud Client library for Cloud IoT for Python too (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/iot/index.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that the newer Python library is technically in Alpha and does not have the standard SLOs associated with it. With that said, I do recommend trying it to see if we can isolate the issue.